# OpenDataCube / cube-in-a-box Installation Problem using PowerShell, Windows 10

Tags: open-data-cube

### [image]435.8 ERROR: Package 'deafrica-tools-2.3.2' requires a different Python: 3.8.10 not in '<3.12,>=3.9'

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cd /tmp   && git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/digitalearthafrica/deafrica-sandbox-notebooks.git   && pip install deafrica-sandbox-notebooks/Tools   && rm -rf /tmp/deafrica-sandbox-notebooks" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1